# Shortest path based on priority

Tags: qgis, geoprocessing, shortest-path

I'm using the geoprocessing "Shortest path (from layer to point)" of QGIS and i'd like to get the shortest path not in the usually way, but based on priority of the routes used.

For example, at a crossroad the priority goes to the green routes despite the greater length:

[image]

Which parameter of a geoprocessing should i set to get priority for the paths?

Comment: You should provide a bit more information. Normally, this makes sense if e.g. the green one is an express highway, the red one a country road - so travelling the green one is faster, thus produces less cost. You should model your data accordingly by adding an attribute with the values of the speed and then use this field in the tool for `Speed field [optional]`.

Comment: It works! Thx!!